# Angular - Firestore - Get Subcollections

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have the following class models:

```js
export class Employee {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

export class Company {
    id: string;
    employees: Employee[];
}
```

I am using angularfire. I am successfully able to retrieve a company record as an Observable using the following syntax:

```js
 this.afs.doc < Company > (`companies/${companyID}`).valueChanges();
```

When I run subscribe() on the above, the Company object that is returned does not include any records for Employees.

Employees are a Sub Collection in Firebase Cloud Firestore.

I know I am able to fetch all the sub collections using:

```js
this.afs.doc < Company > (`companies/${companyID}`).collection('employees').valueChanges();
```

However, I am not sure how I can associate the result with the Company model so that I can simply do company.employees to retrieve all employees.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: when you run subscribe, can you post what you are getting in console.log()?

Comment: Have you found an answer for this yet?